# typescript `Parameters` when calling method by name

Tags: typescript, function, object, parameters, call

I am trying to type correctly following code:

```js
interface SomeObject {
  fn1: (params: { a: string, b: object }) => void,
  fn2: (params: { c: number }) => number,
  fn3: () => number
}

type Methods = keyof SomeObject;

let someObject: SomeObject = {
  fn1: ({ a, b }) => console.log(a, b),
  fn2: ({ c }) => c,
  fn3: () => 1
}

const fn = <T extends Methods>({ method, parameters }: {
  method: T,
  parameters: Parameters<SomeObject[T]>
}) => {
  const _method = someObject[method]

  _method(parameters[0]);
}

fn({ method: 'fn1', parameters: [{a:'str', b:{}}] });
```

The problem that I encountered is that `_method` gets a following type:

```js
const _method: (params: {
    a: string;
    b: object;
} & {
    c: number;
}) => number | void
```

So it takes an intersection of all possible parameters and thus making it impossible to use the `fn({ method, parameters })` notation. Is there any workaround? (without using `as` or `any`)

You can find TypeScript playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2EDyAjAKwgTGQG8AoZZGEARgC5kAKABzijkwGcmzk4TbmCigA5gBpkeJukLFSAXwCUyALwA+ZADd0wACYSqNEACYmbDl17lkCJiACumPNGQr1Wpy+hHqtAGYLVU1kb1coCkUKCjAAT1YUAFkIMAALdH1udWQAawg49Bg0LFx5EgBuGIR0EGFkblL8IhImDGxmhRzKf3oLfjgpPHcQrRq69AAbCAA6SfQxZkHpZT8TcxZ+BBHPOzXA4N26KKqKcfraHIAeABVkCAAPSBAs5BT0zO4NZn5sD8NkOxOH9oNlFHxjH8MvomDc1kCuKlQUwAApWEFQbhXdplFpgADaNwAuhooqNyMZzqQAPpQzI5RodcoEun6Ikxai01LQyzApGY-EABiJyiqilOtB+yFZTAA5LQ6LKpAiMTZ8QMGLLhFAldIGGRFO4iSMKkA).

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a small trick how to make it work:

```js
interface SomeObject {
  fn1: (params: { a: string, b: object }) => void,
  fn2: (params: { c: number }) => number,
  fn3: () => number
}

type Methods = keyof SomeObject;

const someObject: SomeObject = {
  fn1: ({ a, b }) => console.log(a, b),
  fn2: ({ c }) => c,
  fn3: () => 1
};

type Args<T extends Methods> = {
  method: T,
  parameters: Parameters<SomeObject[T]>
}
const fn = <T extends Methods>(method: T, callback: (method: SomeObject[T]) => any) => callback(someObject[method]);

fn('fn1', (method) => method({ a: 'sdf', b: {} })) // ok
fn('fn1', (method) => method({ a: 2, b: {} })) // expected error

fn('fn2', (method) => method({ c:42})) // ok
fn('fn2', (method) => method({ c:'42'})) // expected error

fn('fn3', (method) => method()) //ok
fn('fn3', (method) => method(2)) //expected error
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2EDyAjAKwgTGQG8AoZZGEARgC5kAKABzijkwGcmzk4TbmCigA5gBpkeJukLFSAXwCUyALwA%20ZADd0wACYSqNEACYmbDl17lkCJiACumPNGQr1Wpy%20hHqtAGYLVU1kb1coCkUKCjAAT1YUAFkIMAALdH1udWQAawg49Bg0LFx5EgBuGIR0EGFkblL8IhImDGxmhRzKf3oLfjgpPHcQrRq69AAbCAA6SfQxZkHpZT8TcxZ%20BBHPOzXA4N26KKrYhJQAQSgxbgAeABVkCAAPSBAs5BT0zO4tNXJjNhvvomPc1uxOEDoDYAApWKFQO7tMotMAAbXuAF0NFEKON6rQcg8nq8IO9sl8MlkNMwgVTQVIEHBJpM8IhchY6Zk2k1yuisaMBCA4oKmSy2QhcsxGh0%20WiufpMcpTrRmAByWh0NVSWmpKmChXMAZMNXcfQwbXSPiKEaqAD0duQ6FyFFVGvolt1wINesyRoETFMQ2ttuQDpJiRIEH0TygUHQkVdIHVtFMnoVPuB-vsABZTCp7Y7nUmU2Z0779JmqdmGGq82qC2HHS9I5AY9B44m3YFy97doblIXi92QAFe-r%20xXmKZB02Wwpo7HO0A)

I'm not specialist in type system theory, but I'd willing to bet the the problem caused by contravariance.

I will happy to hear any explanations )

Comment: thank you for your response. I decided to open a bug https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42818 to seek the official explanation